# Spring reactive mongodb template update document partially with objects

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have some class (document) to update in mongo db

The document stored in mongo (real example more complicated):

```
{
   "id": "5ba6b0576cba836aa43ab379",
   "firstName": "First Name",
   "lastName": "Last Name",
   "mobile": "123456789"
   ....................
   ....................
   ....................
   "address": "some address"
}
```

Let's say, I have class Foo with all these fields above.

I receive from outside partial object (Foo with only 3 value, all other values are null), e.g.:

```
{
   "id": "5ba6b0576cba836aa43ab379",
   "mobile": "987654321",
   "address": "other address"
}
```

I want to update document, but with received fields only.

I found only option to do it manually with reactivemongotemplate.
I am looking for more "nice" way without creating manually Update object. Something like:

```
reactivemongotemplate.updateFirst(
    Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is("5ba6b0576cba836aa43ab379")), 
    partialFoo // (object of class is Foo)
)
```

Does anybody knows any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the "nicest" way to do it, but for a rest webservice I'm starting, I've been trying to simplify internally the PATCH and PUT methods and I do it using a Map using the `org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils` library and then I create the Update object I am passing to the `ReactiveMongoTemplate`, more or less like this:

```
Map<String, Object> changes = PropertyUtils.describe(myDto);
// ... check the fields that must be sets and other business rules ...
Update updateFields = new Update();
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : changes.entrySet()){
  updateFields.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
reactivemongotemplate.updateFirst(query(where("id").is(myId)), updateFields, MyEntity.class)
```

This implies that your `MyDto` class has the getters and setters for each field you need, but it is working pretty well so far.

Comment: Thx, I implemented by myself similar solution, but definitely I'll replace with **PropertyUtils** to remove my own code.

Comment: I'm happy it helped ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thats my solution for this case

```java
  public Mono<ProjectChild> UpdateCritTemplChild(
       String id, String idch, String ownername) {

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id")
                              .is(id));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("tasks._id")
                              .is(idch));

    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("tasks.$.ownername", ownername);

    return template
         // findAndModify:
         // Find/modify/get the "new object" from a single operation.
         .findAndModify(
              query, update,
              new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true), ProjectChild.class
                       )
         ;

  }
```

Comment: I think there, the main point was to be able to edit a document partially given only an object, without having to set manually all the fields. Your example works well for a single field change, but if there are dozens of them, or if the fields are dynamic, it can be impossible to use your solution.