# SpringBoot ReactiveMongoTemplate updating document partially

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data, reactor

I am working on a kotlin reactive spring-boot mongodb project. I'm trying to update a document but it does not work well.

My problem is pretty similar to the following question in stackoverflow.

[Spring reactive mongodb template update document partially with objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52463918/spring-reactive-mongodb-template-update-document-partially-with-objects)

So I have a document in mongo

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "MYNAME",
  "email": "MYEMAIL",
  "encryptedPassword": "12345",
  ...........................
}
```

And when I call PATCH on the uri `localhost:8080/user/1` with the one of following header

```
{
  "name": "NEW NAME"
}
```

```
{
  "email": "NEW EMAIL"
}
```

I want to update my document with received fields only.

My handler code

```
fun update(serverRequest: ServerRequest) =
        userService
                .updateUser(serverRequest.pathVariable("id").toLong(), serverRequest.bodyToMono())
                .flatMap {
                    ok().build()
                }
```

My Service Implement code

```
override fun updateUser(id: Long, request: Mono<User>): Mono<UpdateResult> {
    val changes = request.map { it -> PropertyUtils.describe(it) }
    val updateFields: Update = Update()
    changes.subscribe {
        for (entry in it.entries) {
            updateFields.set(entry.key, entry.value)
        }
    }
    return userRepository.updateById(id, updateFields)
}
```

My repository code

```
    fun updateById(id: Long, partial: Update) = template.updateFirst(Query(where("id").isEqualTo(id)), partial, User::class.java)
```

My user code

```
@Document
data class User(
        @Id
        val id: Long = 0,
        var name: String = "",
        val email: String = "",
        val encryptedPassword: ""
)
```

I have followed the advice that [Spring reactive mongodb template update document partially with objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52463918) gave.

My code do updates, but it updates to the initial constructor of my `User` class.

Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to partially update my data.

First I changed the body request to string. (using `bodyToMono(String::class.java`)

Then I changed the changed JSON string to JSONObject(`org.json`).

And for each of its `JSONObject`'s key I created `Update` that will be the partial data to update my entity.

Following is how I implemented this.

```
override fun updateUser(id: Long, request: Mono<String>): Mono<UpdateResult> {
    val update = Update()
    return request.map { JSONObject(it) }
            .map {
                it.keys().forEach { key -> update.set(key, it[key]) }
                update
            }
            .flatMap { it -> userRepository.updateById(id, it) }

}
```

Please share more idea if you have more 'cleaner' way to do this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should consider this problem as a general problem of patching an object in Java/Kotlin. I found an article about this: https://cassiomolin.com/2019/06/10/using-http-patch-in-spring/#json-merge-patch. Even if you won't update partially an object, there should not be such a big impact on performance of your application.